# How Drawable xml files are identified ?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-xml

When i put following xml file in 'drawable' folder, the drawable is automatically compiled to 'GradientDrawable' and i'm able to use it in layout

but in xml file, i haven't specified its data type 'GradientDrawable'.

where this xml parsing and 'automatic' type detection happens ? during compilation time or at runtime ?

If i write a custom drawable, can i specifiy its parameters as xml markup in a similar way?

I found [Drawable.inflate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#inflate%28android.content.res.Resources,%20org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.util.AttributeSet%29) method, but couldn't find usage examples

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        a:angle="270"
        a:endColor="#992f2f"
        a:startColor="#ef4444" />
    <stroke
        a:width="1dp"
        a:color="#992f2f" />
    <corners a:radius="6dp" />
    <padding
        a:bottom="6dp"
        a:left="6dp"
        a:right="6dp"
        a:top="6dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

in Java you should use R.drawable.ExamplePicture
on xml  ="@drawable/ExamplePicture"
with the picture file on each  drawable-xx folder